# When changing date - I get "2" instead of "02"

Tags: jquery

[I built a slider where you can pick a data and slide a slider.](http://jsfiddle.net/LUr6b/2/)
The issue is, when I choose "2013-02-01" from the datepicker and move the slider to something like 1am, I get "2013-02-2" instead of "2013-02-02".

Here is my code:

```
$("#when").datepicker();


$("#open-till").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1230,
    min: 1200,
    max: 1860,
    step: 30,
    slide: slideTime
});
slideTime();

$("#SearchButton").click(function () {
    SendData();
});
function slideTime(event, ui) {
    var val0 = ui == undefined ? 1230 : ui.value,
        minutes0 = parseInt(val0 % 60, 10),
        hours0 = parseInt(val0 / 60 % 24, 10)
        startTime = getTime(hours0, minutes0);
    $("#time").text(startTime);
}

function getTime(hours, minutes) {
    minutes = minutes == 0 ? '00' : minutes + "";
    hours = hours + "";
    if (hours.length == 1) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

function SendData() {
    var WhenDateUnformatted = $('#when').val().split('/');
    var startTimeSPLIT = startTime.split(':');


    var parsedWhenDateUnformatted = parseInt(WhenDateUnformatted[1], 10);
    if (startTimeSPLIT[0] < 20) {
        WhenDateUnformatted[1] = (parsedWhenDateUnformatted + 1).toString();
    }


    var WhenDate = WhenDateUnformatted[2] + '-' + WhenDateUnformatted[0] + '-' + WhenDateUnformatted[1] + ' ' + startTime + ':00';
    alert(WhenDate);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parsedWhenDateUnformatted = parseInt(WhenDateUnformatted[1], 10);
if (startTimeSPLIT[0] < 20) {
    WhenDateUnformatted[1] = (parsedWhenDateUnformatted + 1).toString();
    if (WhenDateUnformatted[1].length == 1) {
        WhenDateUnformatted[1] = "0" + WhenDateUnformatted[1];
    }
}
```

you forced that value into an int (which has no leading zero), manipulated it, then converted it back.
after the conversion backwards, you need to add a leading zero, if you need to.

The inner `if` fixes that in the same way as for hours some lines above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `day` is `WhenDateUnformatted[1]` which, for example, is equal to `"01"`.

1. You are converting `day` from string to a number using `parseInt`, that's from `"01"` to `1`.
2. Then you add `1` to `day`, that's from `1` to `2`.
3. Finally you are converting `day` to string, that's from `2` to `"2"`.

At the end you are concatenating a number with a different format than you had initially. You can keep the format if you slightly modify the conversion at step 3 as below.

```
WhenDateUnformatted[1] = ("0" + (parsedWhenDateUnformatted + 1)).substring(0, 2);
```

[See a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7GEUX/)